# Search and filter rows in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this table and what I want to do is **search by *email* and *name*** so when I type `"one"` it should start filtering out the rows the match the search value.
I am very new to JS / jQuery. Can this be done somehow? (PS: I don't want to use AJAX to load it.)

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '#searchme', function() {
  // ... I'm lost in here about the necessary logic
});
```

```html
<input id="searchme" name="searchme" type="text" class="form-control">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>name</th><th>Email</th><th>Status</th><th>Date</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Nameone</td>  <td>oneName@email.com</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>NameTwpo</td> <td>twoName@email.com</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What research have you done? There should be numerous examples around for  doing this. There are also lots of table scripts with integrated search. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. If you have actually tried something show what you have tried that isn't working an people will help you fix **your code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the `"input"` EventName
- Use [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to match a string case insensitive
- Use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and its `.toggle()` Method to toggle a CSS class like `.is-hidden`

```js
// (No need to use jQuery)

// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);

// Helper functions:

// Escape RegExp special characters:
const regEsc = (v) => v.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');

// Task:

// Search filter rows:
const elsTr = els("#searchtable tr");
const elSearch = el("#searchme");

const filterRows = (evt) => {
  const val = evt.currentTarget.value.trim(); // Trim from whitespaces
  const reg = new RegExp(regEsc(val), "i"); // "i" = case insensitive
  
  elsTr.forEach(elTr => {
    return elTr.classList.toggle("is-hidden", !reg.test(elTr.textContent));
  });
};

elSearch.addEventListener("input", filterRows);
```

```css
.is-hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<input id="searchme" name="searchme" type="text" class="form-control">
<table id="searchtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> John</td>
      <td> john.doe@aaa.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Anna</td>
      <td> anna.doe@bbb.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> John</td>
      <td> john.zoe@bbb.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this one is working perfectly , thnks sir

Comment: @Taoufik added the missing regex escaper for sensitive regexp characters. Edited. Thx BTW :)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are using jQuery, I would suggest using something tried and tested such as [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). It has many pros such as a mobile responsive design, sorting and filtering etc.

As per their instructions:

Include the CSS:

```
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
```

Include the JS:

```
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

Initialise DataTables:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

Unless this is an exercise in learning how to make a search, I don't think it is necessary to ["*reinvent the wheel*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel).

**Update #1**

As per your comment, the searching should be enabled by default, but in the instance that it isn't you could explicitly tell it to enable the search:

```
$('#my-table').DataTable({
    "searching": true
});
```

**Reading Material**

[searching](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searching)

Comment: actaully i am using datatables but it does show the search input field

Comment: isnt it true by default, btw i already tried that and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can use some thing like this (i used for my project)(*you should set id to your table*):

```
$("#searchme").keyup(function() {
    var rows = $("#fbody").find("tr").hide();
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    var _rows = $();//an empty jQuery collection
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        _rows.add(rows.filter(":contains('" + v + "')");
    });
    myFunction(_rows);
});
```